# Find the Big Theta (Θ) value for a given function

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, linear-algebra, complexity-theory

I am learning Data Structures and Algorithm, I saw a problem in one of the DS book which says to prove

```
(n + a)^b = O(n^b)
```

It means that the L.H.S should be equal to Big O of n^b.

I found a solution which says that:

```
(n+a)^b ≤ cn^b (1) 
(n+a)^b ≤ (n+n)^b for n>a and a>0 (2) 
(n+n)^b ≤ 2n^b for c=2 and n0 >a
```

My question is that at line number 2, how did the value became (n+n)^b from (cn^b).
It might be a very lame doubt but I am having a hard time in getting it absorbed. I already know anbout Big Theta, Big O and Big Omega notations.
I will really appreciate help on this.

Comment: If `n > a` then `(n + a) < (n + n)`.

Comment: answered by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267341/show-that-n-ab-thetanb

Comment: Thats the solution but its really difficult to comprehend, any other place where I could get it. @MitchWheat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a very simple thing if you notice, `(n+a)^b ≤ cn^b`  and vice versa. Here, `n>a and a>0` so the inequality is if  `(n+a)^b ≤ cn^b`  then `cn^b` will become `(n+a)^b` or `(n+n)^b` when the condition applies.

I proved it using the binomial expansion. You can look it and if you carefully notice you will find why `cn^b` becomes `(n+n)^b`

you can find [binomial solution here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267341/show-that-n-ab-thetanb)

Comment: Thats what I found  math.stackexchange.com/questions/267341/show-that-n-ab-thetanb but I am unable to comprehend it, any other way